# Conversion to string 'System.data.dataRowView' to type integer is invalid in vb.net with 2 dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a small problem in my vb.net code. The error is

> conversion to string 'System.data.dataRowView' to type integer is invalid

How can I fix it? I have 2 dropdownlist, first one; when I choose an option, all the data related to that option, should appear in the second dropdownlist. Part of my code:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder             
sb.Append("select date_collected, spectral_id from Spectral_information")                 
sb.Append("inner join Crop on crop_id = si_crop_id")                 
sb.Append("where si_crop_id =")                 
sb.Append(CInt(crop.SelectedValue.ToString())) 
Dim str As String = sb.ToString()
```

etc..

Comment: Your code seems to have nothing to do with your description. Your error message is not in its original format, did you change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
sb.Append(CInt(crop.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

seems silly doesn't it? Why convert the selected value to string, then int, then back to string in [StringBuilder.Append(Integer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43wt5x6h(v=vs.110).aspx)? If you expect an Integer there, then you have an issue when there isn't. You should address that first. Changing the line to this

```
sb.Append(crop.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

should make it work. Then you need to address the logic.